# How to find in an array from right without reversing?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains version numbers. They are sorted, but sparse. An example could look like this:

```
const versions = [
  { version: 1, data: { ... }},
  { version: 3, data: { ... }},
  { version: 17, data: { ... }},
  { version: 95, data: { ... }}
];
```

Now if I want to access version `17`, things are easy:

```
const data = versions.find(item => item.version === 17);
```

But what if I want to access version `16`, e.g.? From the domain point of view what I would like to get is the **highest** version that was released **before** the desired version, in this case version `3`.

If we combine both queries, this basically means that I am looking for the last entry in the array that is `<=` the desired version. Now the problem is: How to do that efficiently.

Things would be really easy if there was a `findRight` function on arrays, because then I could write:

```
const data = version.findRight(item => item.version <= 16);
```

This would return version `3`. If we ran the same command with `17`, it would return version `17`. The only problem here is: There is no `findRight` function in JavaScript

I can think of two possible workarounds:

- First, `reverse` the array, and then use the normal `find` function. This unfortunately becomes quite slow, as I need to run this query *lots* of times in a loop for different version arrays.
- Second, implement a custom `findRight` function. This would work, but this sounds like solving a problem that has already been solved by someone else.

Before I go to implement my own function – is there a better (i.e. faster) approach that works with pure JavaScript and without npm modules?

Comment: Return an array that contains all versions smaller than 17 and then take the last item from that array.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks for this idea, but this is less efficient than running a `find`, as a `filter` needs to process the entire array, and doesn't stop at the desired item. So yes, from a technical point of view it works, but I would like to have a more performant solution here.

Comment: You can use lastIndexOf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use "reduceRight" for this like below

```js
const versions = [
  { version: 1, data: 1},
  { version: 3, data: 3},
  { version: 17, data: 17},
  { version: 95, data: 95}
];

function getNextVersion(v) {
  return versions.slice(0).reduceRight((a , b, i , arr) =>  b.version <= v ? (arr.length = 0, b) : b)
}

console.log(getNextVersion(16))

console.log(getNextVersion(17))

console.log(getNextVersion(18))

console.log(getNextVersion(2))
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but `reduceRight` always processes the entire array, and does not stop at the correct one. This could be a performance problem, unfortunately :-(

Comment: No this would stop when it finds the result. That's why I have intentionally did .slice() and arr.length = 0

Comment: By doing .slice makes a copy and send it as 4th parameter in "reduce" and when we get the desired result we just return result and empty that copied array. This way entire array is not processed. At least this is what I think so. :)

Comment: Aaahhhhh! Now I got it! This is pretty clever 

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of targeted item and then use it to get before release element.

> The `findIndex()` method returns the *index* of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns *-1*, indicating no element passed the test

```js
const versions = [{
    version: 1,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    version: 3,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    version: 17,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    version: 95,
    data: {}
  }
];

var index = versions.findIndex(item => item.version === 17);
console.log(versions[index - 1])
```

Comment: What if I want to search `16`, not `17`?

Answer (score 1):

You can take last item from the filtered array which is nothing but the previous *version*:

```js
const versions = [
  { version: 1, data: {  }},
  { version: 3, data: {  }},
  { version: 17, data: {  }},
  { version: 95, data: {  }}
];

const data = versions.filter((item,idx) => item.version < 17);
const previousV = data[data.length -1];
console.log(previousV);
```

Comment: In contrast to the accepted answer this always processes the entire array and doesn't stop early.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generator, which returns the elements from the right side.

```js
function* iterRight(array) {
    var i = array.length;
    while (i--) yield array[i];
}

const versions = [{ version: 1, data: {} }, { version: 3, data: {} }, { version: 17, data: {} }, { version: 95, data: {} }];

var item;

for (item of iterRight(versions)) {
    if (item.version <= 16) break;
}

console.log(item);
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but introducing a generator function seems to be a little overkill here. Nevertheless, great idea!

Answer (score 1):

just use `reduceRight()`

```js
const versions = [
  { version: 1, data: {}},
  { version: 3, data: {}},
  { version: 17, data: {}},
  { version: 95, data: {}}
];

console.log(versions.reduceRight((a,b) => a.version <= 16 ? a : b ));
```

Comment: In contrast to the accepted answer this always processes the entire array and doesn't stop early.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, hope it helps.

```
console.log( versions.find((item, index, arr) => item.version <= 16 && arr[index+1].version > 16) );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dummy9807/o0z5xvrk/8/

Comment: This is IMHO the second-best answer. It works, stops early, but its only drawback is that it processes the array from left to right (which in my case is worse than processing it from right to left, as newer versions are more often needed than older ones).

Answer (score 1):

If we presume that next is true:

1. Array is sorted
2. We will always search for an existing item

then You could use the index of the current item:

e.g.

```
var data = versions.find((element, index, array) => { return array[index+1].version === 17 });
```

This way you will get element before the version your are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, assumption 2 is not given in my case :-(

Comment: Then you could check if next elemet exists and if it doesn't return false before cobdidion check.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [Array.findLast()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast) (supported in major browsers since 2022)

```
const versions = [
  { version: 1, data: { }},
  { version: 3, data: { }},
  { version: 17, data: { }},
  { version: 95, data: { }}
];
const data = versions.findLast(item => item.version <= 16); // { version: 3, data: { }}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a filter and get the last element

```js
const versions = [{
    version: 1,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    version: 3,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    version: 17,
    data: {}
  },
  {
    version: 95,
    data: {}
  }
];

function fun(val) {
  let k = versions.filter(item => {
    return item.version < val
  })
  return k[k.length - 1].version

}

console.log(fun(17))
```

Comment: In contrast to the accepted answer this always processes the entire array and doesn't stop early.